How to compile luaplus53 in ubuntu20.04?
I followed the readme file to compile the luaplus53 program under https://github.com/jjensen/luaplus51-all, and the final compilation result directory is as follows:
.build::~/luaplus/.build$ ll
total 48
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Dec  2 02:25 ./
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4096 Dec  2 02:24 ../
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Dec  2 02:26 bin.lua53-luaplus.gcc.linux64/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  358 Dec  2 02:24 buildenvironment.config
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  102 Dec  2 02:24 customsettings.jam
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   89 Dec  2 02:24 jam*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  177 Dec  2 02:24 Jambase.jam
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  600 Dec  2 02:24 Jamfile.jam
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Dec  2 02:25 linux64/
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  165 Dec  2 02:24 updatebuildenvironment*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  176 Dec  2 02:24 updateworkspaces*
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec  2 02:24 _workspaces_/

bin.lua53-luaplus.gcc.linux64/：
total 5480
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1494992 Dec  2 02:25 liblua53.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   62688 Dec  2 02:25 lua
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2906824 Dec  2 02:25 lua53-luaplus-static.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1131440 Dec  2 02:25 luac
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Dec  2 02:25 lib
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Dec  2 02:26 share

I found that no dynamic library for luaplus was generated, only a static library lua53-luaplus-static.a was produced. I tried linking lua53-luaplus-static.a in my project, but encountered the following error during make:
/luaplus/.build/bin.lua53-luaplus.gcc.linux64/lua53-luaplus-static.a(LuaState_DumpObject.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_ZTVN7LuaPlus15LuaStateOutFileE' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I tried linking liblua53.so, and the compilation passed, but encountered the following error during runtime:
@ubuntu:~/projects/WD/ServiceLauncher/bin$ ./pmds_debugger ../files/Half-your-data/app.xml -s > log
./pmds_debugger: symbol lookup error: /home/zsl/projects/WD/ServiceLauncher/lib/libpmds_core.so: undefined symbol: lua_pcall

I have tried for a long time but haven't solved the problem. I need some help from a guru.

The answer is already given in the error message: recompile with -fPIC. You should follow this advice.

"Actually, I have already tried that, so I think there might be something wrong with how I am using this library."

If liblua53.so does not define lua_pcall, what symbols does it define?
